# Verify detached PKSC #7 signature in java (may be by Bouncy Castle), generated by CAPICOM

Tags: digital-signature

all!

I'm solving two problems:

1. Stop using CAPICOM to sign/verify documents - because it's no longer supported by Microsoft (see more: [Alternatives to Using CAPICOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc778518%28v=VS.85%29.aspx))
2. Flowing out first we want to wide list of supported browsers by our system (customized Documentum webtop). Now it fully supported only by IE 6+ because of CAPICOM used as ActiveX.

For signing we use windows module [CryptoPro](http://www.cryptopro.ru/products/csp/overview) because of only it officially have legal effect in Russia. Our system deployed in government of one Russian region.

Our system works already 5 years and there are many generated signs (all by CAPICOM). Signs is detached and persist in database.

We want to find solution to verify those signs in java code (wrapped in Applet).

I have tried code below, but I can't find any suitable method to verify any signature. This method always returns false.

```
public boolean verifyFile(String fileInput, String metadata, String base64Signature) throws Exception {
    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    byte[] signedContent = Base64.decode(base64Signature.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    CMSSignedData cms7 = new CMSSignedData(signedContent);
    CertStore certs = cms7.getCertificatesAndCRLs("Collection", "BC");
    SignerInformationStore signers = cms7.getSignerInfos();
    Collection c = signers.getSigners();

    SignerInformation signer = (SignerInformation)c.iterator().next();
    Collection certCollection = certs.getCertificates(signer.getSID());
    Iterator certIt = certCollection.iterator();
    X509Certificate cert = (X509Certificate)certIt.next();

    Signature signature = Signature.getInstance("SHA1withRSA", "BC");
    signature.initVerify(cert.getPublicKey());
    String signedContentString = getSignedDataString(fileInput, metadata);
    signature.update(signedContentString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    return signature.verify(signer.getSignature());
}
```

Have somebody any solution or already encountered this pr